# Cannot define Ctypes Structure bit fields over 64 bits. Any alternatives?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to create a Ctypes structure to parse some raw byte arrays, but some of my fields are longer than 64 bits.

I can't figure out any way to define larger bit fields

```py
    class MySpecialStructure(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("a", c_uint, 32),
            ("b", c_uint, 96),
            ("c", c_uint, 96),
            ("d", c_uint, 32),
            ("e", c_uint, 384)
        ]
```

this give me: "ValueError: number of bits invalid for bit field"

Any alternatives to Ctypes that I could use for this? any way to define a bit field over 64bits?

Comment: Bit fields are commonly used to represent integral types of known, fixed bit-widths. You may be able to use something like the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) module to do what you need.

Comment: @martineau these fields are all always a known fixed-bit width, so bit fields would work great if they could be extended over 64 bits. For using bitarray, would you reccomend creating more than one bit array for each field, or one big bit array?

Comment: Yes, but the fields don't correspond to any **standard C** integer bit-widths, which is why the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module doesn't support them.

Comment: @martineau sorry to bother you for an only slightly-relevant question, but It's been suggested that I use arrays of c_uint32 for any fields larger than 64 bits. Can this be done with Ctypes? if so, how?

Comment: Since all the fields are multiples of 32 bits, the easiest thing to do would probably be to use one `bitarray` for them all, and then manually convert it into the five fields they represent. As far as I can tell, these fields are unsigned integers so an array of `c_uint`s would be appropriate. Python integers are variable length and can have any number of bits, so it should be possible (and fairly easy) to convert the `bitarray` elements into 5 Python integers.

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't need to use the `bitarray` module to define an array of `c_uint`s — since that's something I believe `ctypes` can handle.

Comment: "*raw byte arrays*" map to `unigned char [size]`. *bit fields* are not designed for this purpose. This looks like an *XY Problem*. there shouldn't be the need for this approach.